# Assign awk (or sed) output to a variable shell script

Tags: bash, shell, variables, awk, sed

I did find answers to this question, what I don't understand is why what seems to work for other is not working for me.
I have a text file with a list of sample names. I want to extract these samples names individually and assign it to a variable, in order to run an array job.

The file is a samples.txt:

```
sample_id_a
sample_id_b
sample_id_c
```

Using the command:

```
qsub -t 1-3 test_job.sh
```

My script is the following: Using the task id index, I want to retrieve the sample id of line x and assign it to VAR, then print it.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "The increment is ${SGE_TASK_ID}"

VAR=$(awk 'NR==${SGE_TASK_ID}' samples.txt)

echo " The sample is ${VAR}"
```

The output is:(here example for output number 1)

```
The increment is 1
The sample is
```

So SGE_TASK_ID is correct, but I fail to retrieve and echo the corresponding string in my .txt file.

Thank you,
Camille

Comment: Update: In the terminal, if I do `awk 'NR==1' samples.txt`, it works. But if I do `VAR=1` and then `NR==$VAR' samples.txt`, it does not. I do not get an error but the output is nothing.

Comment: Many thanks!!! I did not though of the quotes. You can delete his post I guess.